# Erroneous Data explorer Azure batch -> python SDK uploads escaped json?

Tags: python, mongodb, azure, pymongo

I'm using PyMongo (Python 3.6) to interface with a MongoDB API connected to a DocumentDB which is hosted on Azure. When updating existing _ids in the mongo DB I get the, apparently visual, error that my updated json (bson?) has been escaped. This happens in the Azure Data explorer. See picture.

[image]

The results when I query the database via the client though seem to be valid and in working order. The code fragment I use to upload the data looks as follows:

```
def upsert_data(self, collection: str, data: Any):
    bulk_updates = []
    coll = self._database[collection]

    for item in data:
        bulk_updates.append(
            UpdateOne(
                {"_id": ObjectId(item.pop("_id"))},
                {"$set": item}))

    try:
        coll.bulk_write(bulk_updates)
    except BulkWriteError as bwe:
        pprint.pprint(bwe.details)
```

The self._database[collection] is a client created in the **init**.

The structure of the item (type: dict) roughly looks like:

```
   {
       'varA': 0,
       'varB': 12,
       'varC': [
           {'var2': 23}, 
           {'var2': 24}]
    }
```

Is there anyone that could tell me if I'm doing something wrong? This is the solution I came up with after reading documentation. I'm fairly new at this. Any input would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your so-called **json escaped** meaning. Be covered up or the content is emptied? Your screenshot doesn't look complete either.

I follow your code to try to bulk-update data and it works fine.

Please refer to the snippet code as below:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import UpdateOne

uri = "your connect string"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

bulk_updates = []

for doc in coll.find({}):
    bulk_updates.append(UpdateOne({'_id': doc.get('_id')},{"$set": {"test":"add"}}, upsert=False))

print(bulk_updates)

db.coll.bulk_write(bulk_updates)

print("update success ")
```

Update Documents

[image]

For more Operations you can use with the bulk_write method here is the documentation link: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html